# Recursive function with setTimeout is making jest tests exceed maximum call stack size

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react code that requires to check a service until it answer OK.
In the browser, there is no problem.
When I wrote a test, I've needed to mock the service and the setTimeout, in order to not break it.
Now, I'm facing the problem: Maximum call stack size.

Simplified version:

```
 class Retriable extends Component {

   doRefreshStatus(){
     get('url', response => {
       if(response !== 'OK') {
           createRefresh()
       } 
    })
   }
   createRefresh() {
     setTimeout(this.doRefreshStatus, 5000);
   }

 }
Test:
mock get -> will return immediately the response
mock setTimeout -> will return immediately

test-> 
   mock get -> return 'PROCESSING'; // will keep retrying
   assert...
   mock get -> return 'OK' //will stop the retries
```

The real code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { doGet } from '../../src/commons/connection';

class Retriable extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: null
    };
    this.createRefresh = this.createRefresh.bind(this);
    this.doRefreshStatus = this.doRefreshStatus.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.doRefreshStatus();
  }

  doRefreshStatus() {
    doGet('blablabla', status => {
      if (status !== 'OK') {
        this.createRefresh();
      }
      this.setStatus({status});
    });
  }

  createRefresh() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.doRefreshStatus();
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    return (<span id='current-status'>{this.state.status}</span>);
  }
}

export default Retriable;
```

The test:

```
jest.mock('../../src/commons/connection');
import { mountEvaSceneWithOnlyProps } from '../test-utils';
import { doGet } from '../../src/commons/connection';
import Retriable from './Retriable';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
global.setTimeout = callback => {
  callback();
};

const mockScenario = status => {
  doGet.mockClear();

  doGet.mockImplementation((service, callback) => {
    if (service === 'blablabla') {
      callback({ status });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown service: ', service);
    }
  });
};

describe('Retriable concept test', () => {

  mockScenario('PROCESSING');
  //basicly mount
  let wrapper = mountEvaSceneWithOnlyProps(Retriable, {});

  it('Will not break due to retry indefinitely', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('#current-status').text()).toBe('PROCESSING');
    mockScenario('OK');
    expect(wrapper.find('#current-status').text()).toBe('OK');
  });

});
```

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
> 1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
    | ^
  2 | import { doGet } from '../../src/commons/connection';
  3 | 
  4 | class Retriable extends Component {

  at Retriable.createRefresh (test/commons/Retriable.js:1:1)
  at createRefresh (test/commons/Retriable.js:22:14)
  at callback (test/commons/Retriable.test.js:17:7)
  at Retriable.doRefreshStatus (test/commons/Retriable.js:20:5)
  at doRefreshStatus (test/commons/Retriable.js:30:12)
  at callback (test/commons/Retriable.test.js:9:3)
  at Retriable.setTimeout (test/commons/Retriable.js:29:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that there is a [timer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) option:

```
jest.mock('../../src/commons/connection');
import { mountEvaSceneWithOnlyProps } from '../test-utils';
import { doGet } from '../../src/commons/connection';
import Retriable from './Retriable';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
jest.useFakeTimers(); //-------------------------- IMPORTANT
const mockScenario = status => {
  doGet.mockClear();

  doGet.mockImplementation((service, callback) => {
    if (service === 'blablabla') {
      callback({ status });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown service: ', service);
    }
  });
};

describe('Retriable concept test', () => {

    it('Will not break due to retry indefinitely - multiple results', () => {
    mockScenario('PROCESSING');
    let wrapper = mountEvaSceneWithOnlyProps(Retriable, {});
    expect(wrapper.find('#current-status').text()).toBe('PROCESSING');
    mockScenario('OTHER');
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(); // RUN ALL TIMERS UNTIL THIS POINT

    expect(wrapper.find('#current-status').text()).toBe('OTHER');
    mockScenario('OK');
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(); // AGAIN

    expect(wrapper.find('#current-status').text()).toBe('OK');
  });

});
```

Comment: You can also use `jest.runAllTimers` after your component is mounted